# Как получить данные из массива, не используя много if-elseif?

Tags: java, оптимизация

Есть двумерный массив, содержащий ставку и почасовую оплату. Есть выпадающий список из пяти должностей `JComboBox`, радио-кнопки выбора почасовой оплаты или ставки и поле для ввода отработанных часов.

При нажатии на кнопку в текстовую область должна добавляться строка

```
 // Должность + оклад (для каждой должности почасовой * кол-во часов или фиксированный)
 String s = list_of_workers_model.gesSelectedItem() + "\t" + pay + "руб" + "\n"
```

Проверяю, то что нужно добавлять в поле так:

```
// Если выбрана ставка и первая должность, то забираем из массива фикс. оклад для нее и формируем строку

 if (fixed_rate_radio_button.isSelected() && position_list_model.getSelectedItem()==position_list_model.getElementAt(0)){
           worker_pay = pay[1][0];
           list_of_workers.setText( list_of_workers.getText() + full_name_Text_Field.getText() + " - " + position_list_model.getSelectedItem()+ " - " + worker_pay + "руб" +'\n');
       }
        // Если выбрана почасовая оплата и та же должность
        else if (hour_rate_radio_button.isSelected() && position_list_model.getSelectedItem()==position_list_model.getElementAt(0))
        // заносим в оклад формулу "почасовой оклад" * "кол-во часов"
         houres = Integer.parseInt(hour_field.getText());

           worker_pay = pay[1][1]*houres;
// формируем строку          
 list_of_workers.setText( list_of_workers.getText() + full_name_Text_Field.getText() + " - " + position_list_model.getSelectedItem()+ " - " + worker_pay + " руб" +'\n');

    }
```

Это только первая должность, а их пять. Можно ли как-то оптимизировать код, чтобы не писать по два `if` на каждую должность?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Второе условие `if` не содержит блока `else`, поэтому вторую проверку можно не делать (то есть, если не выбрано по ставке, значит выбрано по часам). Вы можете обращаться к значениям ставки каждой должности по индексу в списке комбобокса (а не пять раз по хардкорным номерам), так же строка вывода результата повторяется, ее надо вынести за условие. вот весь код вашей задачи:

```
worker_index = combobox.getSelectedIndex();
if (fixed_rate_radio_button.isSelected()) {
       worker_pay = pay[worker_index][0];
   } else {
       houres = Integer.parseInt(hour_field.getText());
       worker_pay = pay[worker_index][1]*houres;
}

list_of_workers.setText( list_of_workers.getText() + full_name_Text_Field.getText() + " - " + position_list_model.getSelectedItem()+ " - " + worker_pay + " руб" +'\n');
```

p.s: в вашем примере для первой должности (индекс в комбобоксе = 0) берется индекс массива pay, равный 1, но индексы массивов начинаются с нуля и первой должности будет соответствовать индекс 0 (а не 1, как у вас в вопросе). в моем коде это учтено, но если по каким то неведомым причинам вы намерено пропускаете первую позицию массива `pay`, то нужно прибавить 1 к значению `worker_index`

Comment: у модели списка нет метода getSelectedIndex();

Comment: хорошо, получать значение нужно из JComboBox, не знаю, как он тогда у вас называется, в примере условно `combobox` или добавить в вашу модель метод получения индекса в комбобоксе